# When deploying Django to Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env'

Tags: python, django, heroku

When deploying Django to Heroku, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env' error.

Anyone know why it is looking for that module?

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11
django-forms-bootstrap==3.1.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
Pillow==5.3.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2020.4
requests==2.25.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
stripe==2.55.1
urllib3==1.26.2
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Here is the build log from Heroku:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_ae2377c8_/issuetracker/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
           import env
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: What's your stacktrace? Something is doing `env` somewhere.

Comment: In my case, env is used in settings.py to hide secret key.

Comment: I have updated the first post to include the build log from Heroku. My settings.py is importing 'env' which is in my gitignore file so isn't uploaded to github, so how do I get around this problem?

Comment: You either rewrite your code so it doesn't `import env` or you commit the `env.py` file to your git repo.

Comment: "Anyone know why it is looking for that module? ... In my case, env is used in settings.py to hide secret key"—well, then, it's looking for that module because _you are using that module_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember how to get around this problem now. I needed to add to my settings file:

```
    if os.path.exists('env.py'):
        import env
```

Heroku is working again.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

either remove the `import env` code from the settings.py file and run this code

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```